# how to call dbms_stats in a package

Tags: oracle

I have a package is below

```
CREATE PACKAGE p1
IS
   FUNCTION f1
      RETURN NUMBER;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p1
IS
   FUNCTION f1
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 1;
   END;
BEGIN
   DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats ('WMXT', 'EMP', estimate_percent => 10);
END;
```

and when I am trying to call the function f1 as below

```
SELECT p1.f1 FROM DUAL;
```

I am getting below error,

> ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML

how to proceed ?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Remove the stats gathering step from  the function.

Comment: the purpose of calling dbms_stats is to analyse the tables before the function f1 is called. pls let me know how can I achieve that.

Comment: Move the stats gathering step to a separate procedure and call that explicitly rather than in the package initialisation. Or, use the function without a query e.g. `declare i int := p1.f1; begin null; end;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the call to `DBMS_STATS` part of the function, or just something you want to do later? The current package body should not even compile (you may want to fix that and edit).

If stats is part of f1, ask yourself why you want to collect statistics from a function called in a select? It is not exactly mainstream and probably not the right thing to do. Having said that I *think* (not tested) that an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` should do the job:

```
create or replace package body p1 is
  function f1 return number is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('WMXT','EMP',estimate_percent=>10);
    return 1;
  end;
end;
```

If on the other hand you want to collect statistics separately (not part of f1 or p1 at all) remove that part entirely and run it after compiling p1.